# bitbucket pipeline fails to download maven artifacts

Tags: maven, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Hit the following issue with bitbucket pipelines and can't find out why it might be happening - during the build I recurrently see the following error:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-test/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.pom
Oct 27, 2017 8:19:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
Oct 27, 2017 8:19:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Oct 27, 2017 8:19:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
Oct 27, 2017 8:19:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Oct 27, 2017 8:19:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
Oct 27, 2017 8:19:37 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443

Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bitbucket/radistao/test/before-after-spring-test-runner/0.1.0/before-after-spring-test-runner-0.1.0.pom
2/2 KB       

Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bitbucket/radistao/test/before-after-spring-test-runner/0.1.0/before-after-spring-test-runner-0.1.0.pom (2 KB at 21.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

other libs are downloaded fine, the problem started after I added `before-after-spring-test-runner` library into pom.xml. Locally the build runs as usual from IDE and CLI even after the full repo cleanup.
Can somebody tell what might be the connection between these two facts? :)

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines started closing idle Maven connections that are idle for more than 5 minutes after the last infrastructure update. This affects any build which is running Maven and takes longer than this amount of time because such build will fail with 'connection reset socket exception'.

Some plugins in the Maven lifecycle are triggered after running integration tests and the only workaround is to force Maven to use a new connection on every request using

```
mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.pool=false clean install
```

This, however, affects the build time.